# Do we have an option to protect write and delete level access to other users in S3 bucket in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In case of S3 buckets of AWS. Is there a way we can LOCK a bucket which allows to stop any WRITE/EDIT/DELETE operation on the bucket? Only READ access can be there.

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.  **By default**, all actions are denied, so any permission to write/overwrite/delete that exists is permission *you granted*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

There is a concept, called bucket policies, that allows you to configure both bucket-level and object-key-level policies for your resources. For example, you can grant read-only access to anonymous users by the following policy:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I copy-pasted this example from the official documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2). Please refer to it for more information.

Comment: This answer would be more complete if it explained that `Deny` actions in the bucket policy could be used to prevent a user from performing any actions on the bucket or its objects, even if those actions are allowed by another mechanism, such as IAM user policies, even other `Allow` statements within the bucket policy itself... depending on what OP is really asking.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The original question is too broad- it is more like, 'hey is there something similar to so and so'. That is why I just mentioned the concept of bucket policies without going into too many details. Feel free to edit :-)

Comment: Actually -- I think you're right.  I think I must have read more specificity into the question than was actually there, as I was thinking in terms of existing buckets and existing users with existing write access.